# How can I use groupBy of multiple columns by passing in a variable rather than a literal

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to create a val s which has the columns of the dataframe that I want to group. Then I want to pass s to the function groupBy.

If I am using a val with only one column it is working.
I have tried Seq, Array etc. but no luck.

```
val s = "lastname"

df.groupBy(s)  // <<<<---- WORKING !

val t = Seq("lastname", "firstname")

df.groupBy(t) //  <<<---- NOT WORKING !
```

Comment: Try `df.groupBy(t : _*)`.

Comment: not working =>  no `: _*' annotation allowed here (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)

Comment: Try `df.groupBy(t.head, t.tail : _*)`. You must be sure there is at least one element.

Comment: Thanks much !  makes sense, when I look at the signature of groupBy()

Answer (score 1):

Convert the Seq in Seq of columns and avoiding the one element case

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val t = Seq("lastname", "firstname").map(col(_))
df.groupBy(t:_*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass an array to groupBy

```
df.groupBy(t.head, t.tail:_*)
```